# Could not include font definition file: times

Tags: php, drupal-6, tcpdf

I got this problem when I used TCPDF in Drupal 6.

[image]

I changed the halvetica to times.
As I read the theads about this error. I already configured the configuration file at **config/tcpdf_config.php** I already change the **K_PATH_MAIN** to **/sites/all/modules/PDF-IDcard/tcpdf/** is the path correct?

THANKS for response!

Comment: where is the path of `times` file?

Comment: the 'times' file is located here C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal6\sites\all\modules\PDF-IDcard\tcpdf\fonts